# Publish to IIS ASP.Net Core causes "Value cannot be null" error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis

I have an ASP.Net Core application that works in developer mode under IIS Express.  I have published to my Windows 10 IIS site, but I get the following error:

```
An error occurred while starting the application.
ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: implementationInstance
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionServiceExtensions.AddSingleton<TService>(IServiceCollection services, TService implementationInstance)

ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: implementationInstance
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionServiceExtensions.AddSingleton<TService>(IServiceCollection services, TService implementationInstance)
NSG.WebSrv.Startup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) in Startup.cs
-
            // services.Configure<AuthSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("AuthSettings"));
            AuthSettings _authSettings = new AuthSettings();
            _authSettings = Options.Create<AuthSettings>(
                Configuration.GetSection("AuthSettings").Get<AuthSettings>()).Value;
            services.AddSingleton<AuthSettings>(_authSettings);
            //
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });
            // Add MediatR from MediatR.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection package
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConventionBasedStartup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.EnsureApplicationServices()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.Initialize()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()

Show raw exception details
.NET Core 4.6.28207.03 X64 v4.0.0.0    |   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting version 2.2.7-servicing-10089    |    Microsoft Windows 10.0.18362    |   Need help?
```

With the error occurring on the following line:

```
   services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
```

The IIS site App-Pool is configured with *No Managed Code*.

The deployed/translated *web.config* is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <!-- For more info see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=838655 -->
  <!--   -->
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="aspNetCore" />
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <!-- https://scottsauber.com/2017/04/10/how-to-troubleshoot-an-error-occurred-while-starting-the-application-in-asp-net-core-on-iis/  -->
    <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\NSG.WebSrv.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="InProcess">
      <environmentVariables>
        <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
      </environmentVariables>
    </aspNetCore>
  </system.webServer>
  <!--   -->
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: bcfdd09f-8928-4e80-a804-82728c9bbe16-->
```

If I comment out the block of code that it errors, then it errors on the next line of code.

The beginning of the Startup is as follows:

```
public class Startup
{
    //
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
        LoggerFactory = loggerFactory;
    }
    //
    /// <summary>
    /// IConfiguration, common configuration provider.
    /// </summary>
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    //
    /// <summary>
    /// The logger factory
    /// </summary>
    public static ILoggerFactory LoggerFactory = null;
    //
    /// <summary>
    /// The configured logger (console).
    /// </summary>
    public static ILogger<ConsoleLoggerProvider> AppLogger = null;
    //
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        //
        services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(options =>
        {
            // do not use windows authentication
            options.AutomaticAuthentication = false;
        });
        // Configure logging
        // Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger' while attempting to activate 'NSG.WebSrv.Infrastructure.Notification.NotificationService'
        services.AddLogging(builder => builder
            .AddConfiguration(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"))
            .AddConsole()
            .AddDebug()
        );
        AppLogger = LoggerFactory.CreateLogger<ConsoleLoggerProvider>();
        services.TryAdd(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<ILoggerFactory, LoggerFactory>());
        services.TryAdd(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton(typeof(ILogger<>), typeof(Logger<>)));
        // Add and configure email/notification services
        services.Configure<MimeKit.NSG.EmailSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("EmailSettings"));
        services.Configure<ServicesSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("ServicesSettings"));
        services.Configure<ApplicationSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("ApplicationSettings"));
        // services.Configure<AuthSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("AuthSettings"));
        AuthSettings _authSettings = new AuthSettings();
        _authSettings = Options.Create<AuthSettings>(
            Configuration.GetSection("AuthSettings").Get<AuthSettings>()).Value;
        services.AddSingleton<AuthSettings>(_authSettings);
        //
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

The complete solution is on [GitHub](https://github.com/PHuhn/Net-Incident-Core).

Comment: It crashes on services.AddSingleton<AuthSettings>(_authSettings);. Are you 100% sure that appSettings are loaded ?

Comment: No, I am not sure that _authSettings are loaded.  I fact I have made a minimum application and it seems to fail if I add that block of code.

Comment: I did not have correct **appsettings.json** installed, but it basically pointed to the fact that any previous failure can cause this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a new solution and published it, and the template worked. I then added my *Program.cs* and some of my *Startup.cs* file and got it to fail. It failed on **_authSettings**, because I did not have the correct **appsettings.json** installed, but it basically pointed to the fact that any previous failure can cause this problem.  Then I found a line of coded that I had added very early on when I knew nothing about logging, remove the line and it now works:

```
services.TryAdd(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton(typeof(ILogger<>), typeof(Logger<>)));
```

This did not fail under *IISExpress*, but did cause a problem under *w3wp*.

Note: that is my first .Net Core web application.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed .NetCore HostingBundle for IIS?

Comment: I have **dotnet-sdk-2.2.207-win-x64**, **aspnetcore-runtime-2.2.8-win-x64** and **dotnet-hosting-3.1.0-win** installed.

Comment: I just downloaded **dotnet-hosting-2.2.0-win** and installed and recycled IIS and still the same issue.

Comment: I had previously created a new solution and published it, and the template had worked.